# How to use string type column in SQL pivot

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like  below

```
Name       Year       Bonus 
----      -----      ------
Ram       2011        1000
Ram       2011        2000
Shyam      2011       'No Bonus'
Shyam      2012       5000
```

I want to display the total bonus year wise for each person.I tried below query

```
SELECT [Year],[Ram],[Shyam] FROM   
(SELECT Name, [Year] , Bonus FROM Employee )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(Bonus) FOR Name IN (Ram,Shyam)) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY [Tab2].[Year]
```

My Output Should be like below

```
Name      2011          2012
----      ------        ------
Ram        3000         0
Shyam     'No Bonus'    5000
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Your query does not look like using MySQL. Please retag the question with the specific RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Is there an error message or unexpected output?

Comment: Bonus column is string type but sum()  expects decimal. How can i handle this

Comment: What's your dbms in sql?

Comment: You cannot sum numbers and string. Use 0 (zero) instead of 'No Bonus'

Comment: I want to display string result like 'no bonus' in the pivot table.

Comment: @sandeep.mishra What's your expected result if there are `'No Bonus'` and  Bonus in the same year?

Comment: @D-Shih, I have updated my question.Please check what I want in the output result

Comment: In MS Sql Server (2012+) you could use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) to cast it to a number type, and if the varchar doesn't contain a number the TRY_CAST would return NULL. NULL's aren't summed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dbms is sql-server you can try to use `SUM` condition aggregate function in a `CTE`

then use `CAST` with `coalesce` to make it.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Year,Name,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Bonus LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN  CAST(Bonus AS DECIMAL) ELSE 0 END) total,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus = 'No Bonus' THEN 1 END) cnt
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY Year,Name
)
SELECT Name,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN  Year = 2011 THEN CAST(total AS VARCHAR(50)) END),'No Bonus') '2011',
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN  Year = 2012 THEN CAST(total AS VARCHAR(50)) END),'No Bonus') '2012'
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Name
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5dde62717ad41f22ce9b4fa5ee9d59fa)

If you want to create columns dynamically you can try to use dynamic PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Year,Name,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Bonus LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN  CAST(Bonus AS DECIMAL) ELSE 0 END) total,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus = 'No Bonus' THEN 1 END) cnt
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY Year,Name
)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN cnt > 0 and Year = ' + cast(Year as varchar(5)) + ' THEN ''No Bonus''  WHEN Year = ' + cast(Year as varchar(5)) + ' and cnt = 0 THEN CAST(total AS VARCHAR(50)) END),''0'')' + QUOTENAME(Year)
            FROM CTE c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Year,Name,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Bonus LIKE ''%[0-9]%'' THEN  CAST(Bonus AS DECIMAL) ELSE 0 END) total,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus = ''No Bonus'' THEN 1 END) cnt
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY Year,Name
)
SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' 
from CTE
GROUP BY Name'

exec(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16ff9fafb5c0cd3c3f0e4cf825bbe4e3)

Comment: Please check my updated question and the output I expect

Comment: Can it be possible to show the year column dynamically.I mean suppose there are 4 more years in the table, i donot want to hard code the year

Comment: @sandeep.mishra Ok I edit my answer you can try it.  you can try to use dynamic PIVOT.

Comment: I think 'No Bonus' still not showing in your example. Check for 'Shyam. year 2011

Comment: @sandeep.mishra Ok I fix it:)

Comment: Yes Thanks alot. You are really awesome. You made my day bro :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem the following query is what I understood. Not the ideal solution but this will do.
You can modify the query if you need to make it dynamic.

```
 SELECT [Name]
, case when [2011] = 0 then 'No Bonus' when [2011] is null then '0' else cast([2011] as varchar(50)) end as [2011]
, case when [2012] = 0 then 'No Bonus' when [2012] is null then '0' else cast([2012] as varchar(50)) end as [2012] 
FROM   
(SELECT Name, [Year] , cast(Bonus as int) Bonus FROM Employee)Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(Bonus) FOR Year IN ([2011],[2012])) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY [Tab2].[Name]
```

You need to pass 0 in the table though and then modify in the PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

I would just give up on storing numbers as strings.  I don't see the difference between `0`/`NULL` and `'No Bonus'`, except that the latter makes queries prone to really bad type conversion problems.

So, my advice is to do:

```
SELECT [Year],[Ram],[Shyam]   
FROM (SELECT Name, [Year], TRY_CONVERT(int, Bonus) as Bonus
      FROM Employee
     ) e  
PIVOT (SUM(Bonus) FOR Name IN (Ram, Shyam)) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY [Tab2].[Year] ;
```

You probably don't like that solution -- although I really do strongly recommend it because I have spent way too many hours debugging problems with numbers and dates stored as strings.

So, if you persist with storing values as string, use conditional aggregation and a bunch of logic:

```
select year,
       coalesce( sum(case when name = 'Ram'
                          then convert(varchar(255), try_convert(int, bonus))
                     end),
                 'No Bonus'
               ) as Ram,
       coalesce( sum(case when name = 'Shyam'                           
                          then convert(varchar(255), try_convert(int, bonus))
                     end),
                 'No Bonus'
               ) as Shyam    
from employee e
group by year
order by year;
```